# how to avoid NaN in the text box before adding the other text box values in javascript

Tags: javascript, html

am using the following code to add text box values if any of the textbox is not given value it is showing NaN in total textbox how to avoid it

```
 <script>
     function totalValue()
     {
          var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
          var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
          var c = document.getElementById("c").value;   
          var d = parseFloat(a)+ parseFloat(b)+ parseFloat(c);
          document.getElementById("total").value = d;
     }

 </script>
```

Comment: what do you mean?
if value of a is not given, d has the sum of only b and c?

Comment: `parseFloat('0' + a)`

Comment: but it is not adding those two and giving output as NaN

Answer (score 6):

Try this:

```
 <script>
     function totalValue()
     {
          var a = document.getElementById("a").value || 0;
          var b = document.getElementById("b").value || 0;
          var c = document.getElementById("c").value || 0;   
          var d = parseFloat(a)+ parseFloat(b)+ parseFloat(c);
          document.getElementById("total").value = d;
     }

 </script>
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/AvzwM/

Comment: That won't work. Try to type a string in any input. But you can change it to `(parseFloat(a) || 0)`

Comment: what if strings or characters are given in any of the textboxes?
it is returning NaN

Comment: @meze , you're right at this point and your solutions is very clean and nice . I have actually answered on " is not given value " ..

Answer (score 1):

You can append a `0` to a string:

```
 <script>
     function totalValue()
     {
          var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
          var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
          var c = document.getElementById("c").value;   
          var d = parseFloat('0' + a)+ parseFloat('0' + b)+ parseFloat('0' + c);
          document.getElementById("total").value = d;
     }

 </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<script>
//checks if given text in text box is a number or unwanted string
filterInt = function (value)
{
if(/^\-?[0-9]+$/.test(value))
return Number(value);
return NaN;
}

 function totalValue()
 {
      var a = document.getElementById("a").value;
      var b = document.getElementById("b").value;
      var c = document.getElementById("c").value;   
      a=filterInt(a)||0; //if it is a string, convert it to a Nan and then if NaN,                  convert to zero
      b=filterInt(b)||0;
      c=filterInt(c)||0;
      var d = parseFloat(a)+ parseFloat(b)+ parseFloat(c);
      document.getElementById("total").value = d;
 }
```